# Laravel DB::raw COPY

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

im using Laravel 5.5 and I have a very large file that i need to insert its content into the postgres database.
In my research i saw the COPY function from Postgresql documentation. [Copy function documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html).

I tested the command below in the PgAdmin and works fine.

```
COPY requisitions FROM '/srv/www/billing_log' DELIMITER ',';
```

So i saw that in Laravel we can use something like DB::raw() to execute this commands in postgres. I try using the below code but nothing happens and its show no errors.

```
public function insertFile()
{
    DB::raw("COPY requisitions FROM '/srv/www/billing_log' DELIMITER ','");
    return 'OK';
}
```

The 'OK' is returned and my DB config is working fine on the others methods.

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DB::raw` doesn't execute anything, it just returns an expression to use in the query builder.

You can use `DB::statement()` to execute a raw statement.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries